# Несколько drawable рядом

Tags: android, java

загружаю несколько сторонних картинок в папку `drawable`. создаю `xml` в папке `drawable`. мне нужно сделать так чтобы эти картинки были РЯДОМ размещены на этом `xml`. этот `xml` файл мне нужно задать для фона в `imageView` . как мне это сделать ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, нужно засунуть несколько тэгов bitmap в один drawable xml файл. Вот рабочий [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279169/android-making-a-drawable-xml-composed-of-several-bitmaps) с SO. Ну и конечно [пример](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html) от самих гуглов. Касательно данного случая информацию следует искать в LayerList.

Update:

[Пример](http://myandroidtipsandtricks.blogspot.co.il/2012/09/drawables-part-ii.html) программного создания LayerDrawable.

Comment: нечто похожее я хочу. да. Но в тех ссылках указаны границы в xml-коде. Отсюда следует что нужно знать размер картинки. Если у меня несколько drawable для разных экранов, то реализация будет затруднена.

Comment: Можно создать [LayerDrawable][1] програмно.

     
[1]:http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html#setLayerInset(int

Comment: думаю на этом всё. спасибо!